# Order Users by number of followers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the [acts_as_follower gem](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower), and I'm wondering how can I order my users by the number of followers they have? I'm not really sure where to start with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user `acts_as_followable`:

```
User.all.sort_by(&:followers_count)
```

---

Per [Benedikt Deicke's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411263/order-users-by-number-of-followers/14411392#comment20057509_14411392) below, this solution results in N+1 queries. To prevent this situation, enable eager loading of [`followings`](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower/blob/master/lib/acts_as_follower/followable.rb#L19) for all `User` queries.

```
# models/user.rb    
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_followable
  default_scope :include => :followings
  # ...
end
```

Comment: That worked, but it orders it from the least number of followers to the most. How would I order it from the highest to lowest?

Comment: @AlexSmith  `User.all.sort_by(&:followers_count).reverse`

Comment: @Nishant beat me to it by 4 seconds! That is correct, use [`Array#reverse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-reverse).

Comment: Be aware that this solution will fetch *all* your users from the database and will then do an additional followers count query for each of them. For 100 users in the database this will be 101 queries. For 1000 this will be 1001 and so on.

Comment: Awesome, that worked. I also added the default user scope and everything seems to be working just fine.